# Scheduling sample playback with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to build a drum machine that uses samples instead of oscillators, just for the sake of learning. I'm however having trouble scheduling sounds to play in rhythm for the first two beats. What happens is that the first two beats play out of sync while the rest seem to play in rhythm as intended. This issue doesn't occur when playing oscillators instead of samples.

I read The Tale of Two Clocks and every relevant tutorial I could find but all of them work with oscillators which don't seem to exhibit this issue. The following is just one of the ways I tried to implement the code - I tried OOP and various functional programming versions but the problem occurs with all of them.

In this example I made to functions called playSound() and playKick(). playSound() triggers an oscillator note, whereas the playKick() function triggers a kick sample. Try switching between the two in the scheduler() function to hear how the problem occurs.

```
let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var nextNotetime = audioContext.currentTime;
var startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");
var timerID;
let kickBuffer;
loadKick('sounds/kick.wav');

function loadKick(url) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(xhr.response, decoded => {
      kickBuffer = decoded;
    });
  }
  xhr.send();
}

function playKick(time) {
  let source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  source.connect(audioContext.destination);
  source.buffer = kickBuffer;
  source.start(time);
}

function playSound(time) {

  var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
  osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
  osc.frequency.value = 200;
  osc.start(time);
  osc.stop(time + 0.1);

};

function scheduler() {
    while(nextNotetime < audioContext.currentTime + 0.1) {
        // switch between playSound and playKick to hear the problem
        nextNotetime += 0.5;
        playSound(nextNotetime);
        // playKick(nextNotetime);
    }
   timerID = window.setTimeout(scheduler, 0);
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    scheduler();
  }, false);

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
  }, false);

if(audioContext.state === 'suspended'){
  audioContext.resume();
};
```

As you can see the buffer is preloaded as soon as the file is loaded so that is not the root of the cause. Any suggestions on how to fix the issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Working fix.

```
"use strict";



var audioContext = new AudioContext(),
    futureTickTime = audioContext.currentTime,
    counter = 1,
    tempo = 120,
    secondsPerBeat = 60 / tempo,
    counterTimeValue = (secondsPerBeat / 4),
    timerID = undefined,
    isPlaying = false;


//_____________________________________________BEGIN load sound samples
let kickBuffer;
loadKick('sounds/kick.mp3');

function loadKick(url) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(xhr.response, function(decoded) {
            kickBuffer = decoded;
        });
    }
    xhr.send();
}

function playKick(time) {
    let source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.buffer = kickBuffer;
    source.start(audioContext.currentTime + time);
}


//_____________________________________________END load sound samples


function scheduleSound(time) {
    playKick(time)

}


function playTick() {
    console.log(counter);
    secondsPerBeat = 60 / tempo;
    counterTimeValue = (secondsPerBeat / 1);
    counter += 1;
    futureTickTime += counterTimeValue;
}


function scheduler() {
    if (futureTickTime < audioContext.currentTime + 0.1) {
        scheduleSound(futureTickTime - audioContext.currentTime);

        playTick();
    }

    timerID = window.setTimeout(scheduler, 0);
}


function play() {
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;

    if (isPlaying) {
        counter = 1;
        futureTickTime = audioContext.currentTime;
        scheduler();
    } else {
        window.clearTimeout(timerID);
    }
}



var playStop = document.getElementsByClassName("play-stop-button")[0];

playStop.addEventListener("click",function(){
    play();
})
```